# App Engine standard dispatch.yaml 20 rules limit

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am facing an issue with the 20 limit dispatch.yaml rule

Currently I am using "client".mydomain.com which is easy to setup
But I have some bigger clients who I want to put onto a separate service

My goal was the following,

- Public website
- Put 30-50 clients on service A  using "client".mydomain.com
- Put 1 client on service B using "client".mydomain.com
- Put 20-30 clients on service C

But then using number 3 I need to be creative and use something like "client".2.mydomain.com. I would rather see also just "client".mydomain.com on service C

Now dispatch.yaml does have a 20 rule limit, so putting many clients on a separate service is not possible. Eventually I will run into the limit
Anyone has any ideas on to fix this, or do this in another way.

I am open for any suggestions, I was thinking of putting up an nginx, but not each service has it's own ip, so that also not a possibility. Perhaps some new features or so ?
I could also just setup different "similar" domain names and map those like mydomainapp.com appmydomain.com etc, but that would be a bit too much

Currently my dispatch.yaml looks like

```
dispatch:
  - url: "domain.com/*"
    service: default
  - url: "www.domain.com/*"
    service: default
  - url: "*.domain.com/*"
    service: myapp
  - url: "*/something"
    service: myapp
  - url: "*/*"
    service: default
```

So any ideas on how to make this working for everything so that I can use "client".domain.com for every

Comment: Interesting but the real question rather than moving the clients between services would be, how do you filter your "big" and "normal" clients? Do you have any strategy so far?

Comment: @YeriPelona I have manual onboard, as this is not so simple for a variety of reasons. And most business owners in the branche my saas app is, are not to tech savvy. I provide a "total" package, so clients do not have to worry. That is why I can easily separate big/normal clients

Answer (score 1):

For better routing you can make use of a Load Balancer in front of your App Engine services, and add App Engine as a [NEG](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/serverless-neg-concepts) (Network Endpoint Group).

If you set up the Load Balancer and the NEG, you can then create a [URL Map](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/serverless-neg-concepts#url_map) or even [URL Masks](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/serverless-neg-concepts#url_masks) to determine which service should be handling the request.

With that option you'll be also removing the limit that you've encountered while using the `dispatch.yaml` file to define the routing paths.

Comment: That's correct. An extra benefit would be option to use Cloud Armor which would defend you against DDoS attacks.